# How to align (width wise) bootstrap select dropdown with input box?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap select on my form. just below that I am having an input box.
I would like to have input box's width similar to select box.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <select class="selectpicker">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Relish</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="form-control" id="input_id" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/5L30q27f/8/

In bootstrap-select.css, it appears that width has been set to 220px.
I could use the exact width for my input box but I do not think that would be a good idea, since I suspect on mobile devices bootstrap-select might be changing that width to something else.

Currently, I am controlling my input box's width using columns, but it is not the right solution. ( width appears to vary depending on the screen size ).

I am using bootstarp first time. So there is a good chance that I am overlooking something obvious which is provided by bootstrap to solve this problem.

Could you please point me to a right direction?

Comment: Using columns to set the width of a form element is the way suggested in the Twitter Boostrap documentation: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#column-sizing What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, input box's width needs to match dropdown box's width. As you can see, I have tried using columns but it is not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has a few options for setting the width of an element depending on screen size http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options. changing the gird to use the `xs` option in you fiddle gets the result you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/5L30q27f/9/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but input box's width appears greater than dropdown box's width ( t=at least on my screen ).

Comment: Probably a screen size / resolution difference. You can add multiple or all of the `.col-` classes to size it correctly for difference screens

Comment: I think I solved the problem, using "xs" and looking at the link shared by @feeela I added "form-control" class to "select" element. : please check, https://jsfiddle.net/5L30q27f/10/